# React render single instance of mounted component into different children

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am building a sequential step-based wizard flow that looks something like this:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Wizard footer={<Footer />}>
      <Step1 />
      <Step2 />
    </Wizard>
  );
}
```

the `<Step />` components are mounted/unmounted based on the step the user is currently on.

**Problem:**
I have an expensive component, `<SomeExpensiveComponent />`. It is very computationally expensive to mount, but I need to render it in multiple `<Step />`s. I want to avoid having it mount multiple times in my app:

```js
// ❌ BAD - each step is mounting its own, new instance of SomeExpensiveComponent

const Step1 = () => {
  return (
    <Step.Wrapper>
      <Step.Preview>
        <SomeExpensiveComponent />
      </Step.Preview>
      <Step.Content>Step1</Step.Content>
    </Step.Wrapper>
  );
};

const Step2 = () => {
  return (
    <Step.Wrapper>
      <Step.Preview>
        <SomeExpensiveComponent />
      </Step.Preview>
      <Step.Content>Step2</Step.Content>
    </Step.Wrapper>
  );
};
```

I need to render this component inside of various `<Step />`s, but only want to mount the component one time, and share the single instance between steps. Something like this:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {/*  mount expensive component once, here */}
      <SomeExpensiveComponent /> 
      <Wizard footer={<Footer />}>
        <Step1 />
        <Step2 />
      </Wizard>
    </>
  );
}

const Step1 = () => {
  return (
    <Step.Wrapper>
      <Step.Preview>
        {/* ✅ ...and output that single instance into an "outlet" when this component is mounted */}
        <OutletForExpensiveComponent />
      </Step.Preview>
      <Step.Content>Step1</Step.Content>
    </Step.Wrapper>
  );
};

const Step2 = () => {
  return (
    <Step.Wrapper>
      <Step.Preview>
        {/* ✅ ...and output that single instance into an "outlet" when this component is mounted */}
        <OutletForExpensiveComponent />
      </Step.Preview>
      <Step.Content>Step2</Step.Content>
    </Step.Wrapper>
  );
};
```

The hypothetical "outlet" above would simply dictate different render targets for the single shared instance of `SomeExpensiveComponent`.

At first, it sounds like [React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) might be the solution to this problem:

> Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.

However, it seems Portals are primarily focused on the opposite direction - getting a leaf node to render in a higher scope or different tree, not getting a trunk node to render output into a different leaf node.

**Question**:

- Are portals the right way to accomplish the above? If so, how?
- Is this accomplishable with React Context? If so, how?

**Code / demo**
You can see my current attempt (using React Context) here: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-elgamal-wvhc3h?file=/src/App.tsx

Problems:

- `SomeExpensiveComponent` renders > 1 time on app load.
- `SomeExpensiveComponent` re-renders on navigate.

**I tried this approach with react portal**, which seems closer, but still get 2 renders instead of 1 on page load:
https://codesandbox.io/s/young-bash-iij752?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Depends, what exactly is the expensive part of it? Processing some data, for example, or something else?

Comment: @CertainPerformance it is an iframe rendering an embedded page. It's expensive to load, and I'm also injecting some modifications into the frame that would be lost on subsequent re-renders.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this would work given the different locations the iframe would go to, but you might be able to memoize the created expensive component and then pass it down as a prop to all the children. Context won't help on top of simple passing down, unless your components are pretty nested.